# All sub menu items are being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a navigation menu similar to [sample link](https://www.thyssenkrupp-industrial-solutions.com/en/)

I have created a jquery and css based navigation menu from scratch, which should display the dropdown menu as shown in the above link.I want to achieve dropdown style as shown in the above menu.

I have created 4 depth-level menus and when I open all the menu-items once and when I click on the first depth level menu-item all the menu-items till depth level 4 are being displayed.

click on menu-item1>menu-item1.2>menu-item1.2.2>menu-item1.2.2.2

now click on menu-item1.2 twice (all sub-items are being display instead of only menu-item1.2.1 and menu-item1.2.2)

where I am doing mistake?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.menu-item').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.col ul li').removeClass('active');
    
  });
  
  
  $('.col ul li').click(function(event){   
 
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');    
     $('.col ul li ul').removeClass('active');
  });
  
  
  $('.col ul li ul').click(function(event){   
 
    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  
   $('.col ul ul li ul').click(function(event){   

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
 
});
```

```css
.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown > .col {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

.col {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
   display: none;
  
}


.sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
   display: none;
}
.sub-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
   display: none;
  
}

.active .col {
  display: block;
}
.col .active .sub-col{
  display: block;
}

.col .sub-col .active .sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}
 .col .sub-col .sub-sub-col .active .sub-sub-sub-col{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-1</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="col">
        <ul>
            <li>menu-item: 1.1</li>

            <li>menu-item: 1.2        
              <div class="sub-col">
                <ul>
                    <li>menuitem1.2.1</li>
                    <li>menuitem1.2.2
                      <div class="sub-sub-col">
                        <ul>
                            <li>menuitem1.2.2.1</li>
                            <li>menuitem1.2.2.2
                              <div class="sub-sub-sub-col">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>menuitem1.2.2.2.1</li>
                                    <li>menuitem1.2.2.2.2</li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                    </li>   
                </ul>
              </div><!--sub-col-->
            </li>

        </ul>
      </div>  <!--col-->  
  </div><!--dropdown-->
    
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Click on menu-item-1>menu-item: 1.2>menu-item-1.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

change `.col ul ul li` to `.col ul li ul`  and change `.col ul ul ul li` to `.col ul ul li ul`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.col ul li').removeClass('active');

  });


  $('.col ul li').click(function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

  });


  $('.col ul li ul').click(function(event) {


    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('.col ul ul li ul ').click(function(event) {

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown>.col {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

.col {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sub-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.active .col {
  display: block;
}

.col .active .sub-col {
  display: block;
}

.col .sub-col .active .sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}

.col .sub-col .sub-sub-col .active .sub-sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-1</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="col">
        <ul>
          <li>menu-item: 1.1</li>

          <li>menu-item: 1.2
            <div class="sub-col">
              <ul>
                <li>menuitem1.2.1</li>
                <li>menuitem1.2.2
                  <div class="sub-sub-col">
                    <ul>
                      <li>menuitem1.2.2.1</li>
                      <li>menuitem1.2.2.2
                        <div class="sub-sub-sub-col">
                          <ul>
                            <li>menuitem1.2.2.2.1</li>
                            <li>menuitem1.2.2.2.2</li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <!--sub-sub-col-->
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--sub-col-->
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--col-->
    </div>
    <!--dropdown-->

  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good practice  `Explain your answer.`

Comment: When you open all the sub-items and click on "menu-item1.2"  twice all the sub-items are appearing  I want only menuitem1.2.1 and menuitem1.2.2  to open..

Comment: active class should be removed for every sub-item except the next sub-item

Comment: https://www.thyssenkrupp-industrial-solutions.com/en/products-and-services/cement-plants/  I need this kind of navigation menu

Comment: I have edited my question and mentioned the my inspiration link, your answer is welcome..

Comment: Thanks bhargav fr helping me out,i got up to some extent , i stuck at another point fr this i made new question.Try to help me out for this too...